# Django is not upgrading passwords

Tags: django

I am using Bcrypt_SHA256 for new users, but there are some user accounts in an older system that I have to import that are using PBKDF_SHA256. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading) the passwords should get upgraded on login.

I have a custom authentication function, and when I call it on a legacy account the password does not get upgraded?

```
@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, app, email, password):
    app_user = cls.find_by_email(app, email)

    # User not found
    if not app_user:
        return

    # User found but password incorrect
    if not hashers.check_password(password, app_user.password):
        app_user.failed_logins_count += 1
        app_user.save()
        return

    # Failed login count should be reset to 0 on successful login
    app_user.failed_logins_count = 0
    app_user.save()
    return app_user
```

Here are my settings:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

A user gets returned correctly, but the password doesn't change. Do I need to manually upgrade the password due to my custom function, as the docs aren;t clear there, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're calling [`hashers.check_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L44) with no `setter` argument.

Why not call [`app_user.check_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L229) directly on your `User` instance? It will plug the `setter` in for you.

Comment: Ah, the docs are out of date at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers